# 2d collisions engine for irregular shapes formed with straight equations

Tags: java, math, collision

Contex: I'm trying to make a 2d physic engine, i'm starting to think about how to draw shapes that i could rotate. So i thought i could draw irregular shapes by drawing lines from several equations of straight. Now i have some doubts:

- There is a easy way of draw a straight by giving an equation?
- There is a library that can help me to handle equations?

The reason to use equations instead of using functions to draw lines from x1,y1 to x2,y2 is that i want the equations to calculate collisions between shapes.

- Do you know a book or an article that could help me pull this off?

I'm gonna work in java, for now this is just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert in this field but quick search on `java 2d engine collision engine` returns **dyn4j** library on the first page. You can explore their examples and consequently the implementation code.

https://github.com/wnbittle/dyn4j

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look.